# How to Pass a Function or Parameter Using findNavController().navigate() in Android Navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-navigation

In my Android application, I have a Fragment called "Home" that displays a list of animals. This list is managed by an Adapter named "AnimalAdapter." Additionally, I have a Modal called "ReproductionFilter" that allows users to apply filters to animals, such as category and status.

Problem Description:
The "AnimalAdapter" contains the logic to apply these filters in the "onFiltersChanged" method. Currently, when a filter is changed, I call this method directly in the "Home" Fragment, which updates the list of animals based on the selected filters.

However, I want to allow the "ReproductionFilter" Modal to also be able to update the list of animals based on selected filters. The central question here is how to pass a function (or in some other way notify the Adapter) from the "Home" Fragment to the "ReproductionFilter" Modal so that the Adapter's update can occur from the Modal.

Code in the "Home" Fragment:
The "Home" Fragment contains the initialization of the Adapter and a button that opens the "ReproductionFilter" Modal through navigation.

```kotlin
class Home : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_home) {
    ...
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        ...

        this.setupAdapter()
        this.setUpOpenModalButton()
        ... 
    }

    private fun setUpOpenModalButton() {
        val fab = fragmentView.findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.btn_open_filters)

        fab.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_menu_item_home_to_reproductionFilter)
        }
    }

    private fun setupAdapter() {
        val animalFetchList = FakeIt.randomAnimalList(500)
        adapter = AnimalAdapter(animalFetchList)
        recycler.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

Code in the "AnimalAdapter":
The "AnimalAdapter" contains the "onFiltersChanged" method, responsible for applying the filters and updating the list of animals.

```kotlin
class AnimalAdapter(val originalList: List<Animal>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<AnimalAdapter.AnimalViewHolder>() {
    var mFilteredList = mutableListOf<Animal>()

    ...

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun onFiltersChanged() {
        val selectedSearchString = AppState.searchReproductionString
        val selectedFilters = AppState.selectedFilters

        mFilteredList.clear()
        originalList.forEach { animal ->
            if (animal.id.contains(selectedSearchString)) {
                mFilteredList.add(animal)
                println(animal.id)
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

Code in the "ReproductionFilter" Modal:
The "ReproductionFilter" Modal creates checkboxes that allow users to change filters. The filters are stored in a global object called "AppState." The question here is how to notify the "AnimalAdapter" about changes in filters and allow it to be updated.

```kotlin
class ReproductionFilter : BottomSheetDialogFragment(R.layout.reproduction_filters_modal) {
    val selectedfilters = AppState.selectedFilters
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        var container: LinearLayout

        filterList.forEach { filter ->
            if (filter.type == FilterType.STATUS) {
                container = view.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.ll_status_filter_container)
            } else {
                container = view.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.ll_category_filter_container)
            }
            val cbx = createFilterButton(container, filter)
            cbx.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
                // I WANT TO CALL IT HERE IN A GLOBAL WAY
                if (isChecked) {
                    selectedfilters.add(filter)
                } else {
                    selectedfilters remove(filter)
                }
            }
            container.addView(cbx)
        }
    }
}
```

How can I pass a function (or employ a similar approach) from the "Home" Fragment to the "ReproductionFilter" Modal so that I can execute the update of the "AnimalAdapter" from the Modal?

Any clarification will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[image: image from my app flow]

Comment: Listeners or lambdas won't survive a configuration change or process death and recreation (both of which can happen before your dialog closes). Have you read the guide to [returning a result](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/use-graph/programmatic#returning_a_result) or [sharing data between destinations](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/use-graph/programmatic#share_ui-related_data_between_destinations_with_viewmodel)?